# Different results of numpy.linalg.lstsq on different processors

Tags: python, numpy, intel, amd-processor, openblas

I am pretty confused by the behaviour of the `numpy.linalg.leastsq`.
I generated exactly the same input data, pickled it and moved it on two different machines with different operating system (Ubuntu 16.04 vs Ubuntu 18.04), different processors (AMD on Ubuntu 16.04 vs Intel on Ubuntu 18.04), and the same numpy version 1.16.3.

My matrix has infinite condition number, however with the Intel computer I can find a good solution to the problem (which I know beforehand, for benchmark), while with the AMD computer, the solution is largely different.

I believe this could be caused by the different OpenBLAS implementation of the two architectures.
Any idea how to make the two methods return the same value?
Is it because Intel is using some optimized MKL implementation?

My AMD processor is a Threadripper with the following **cpuinfo**:

```
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 1
model name  : AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x8001129
cpu MHz     : 2200.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 32
core id     : 15
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 31
initial apicid  : 31
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid amd_dcm aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_l2 mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 clzero arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 6786.57
TLB size    : 2560 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate eff_freq_ro
```

while the Intel one has the following **cpuinfo**

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x1d
cpu MHz     : 1668.950
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf
bogomips    : 6147.49
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Clearly I'd prefer to run on AMD since it is a much faster CPU.

Comment: "My matrix has infinite condition number" - there's your problem.

Comment: FP math is not strictly associative because different order of operations results in different rounding in temporaries.  Vectorization of reductions (like the vector/column dot products in a matmul) typically optimize assuming that it is.  It might be pure luck that you got a more accurate result on the Intel CPU.  Or it might be because the AMD CPU has FMA and thus avoids rounding while computing `x*y + z` which may for some reason actually hurt?  Using numerical routines that aren't designed to handle your case (like infinite condition number) exposes you to the vagaries of FP math.